# What is the difference between "Run as administrator" and "Run as Administrator"?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, powershell-7.0

There are two (2) "Run as administrator" menu items. The one at the bottom has a PowerShell icon. The bottom one can change console properties such as font and colors. However, the top one (and running as the logged in user) cannot. What is the difference?

[image]

Comment: Do you have both Power Shell 5 and 7 installed?  That might account for the extra menu item. I have PS 5 only installed and one menu item on both machines here.

Comment: Using the top "Run as administrator" will not permit me to change console properties. The bottom "Run as Administrator" will permit console property changes, but only if using "Run as Administrator." The non-administrator does -not- get the changes. It would be worst-practice to always "Run as Administrator."